# Approximating $\frac{1}{(n+1)^a}-\frac{1}{(n+2)^a}$

Tags: calculus

The claim is that if $f(n) = \frac{1}{(n+1)^a} - \frac{1}{(n+2)^a}$ and $g(n)=\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}$, then $f,g$ have the same order of growth. Indeed, trying out some values in a computer algebra system gives me the following limit values.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0.5,0.6$$ when $a=0.5,0.6$ respectively.

I do not know why this approximation works, so I tried the following derivation.

$\begin{align}\frac{f(n)}{\frac{1}{n^a}}&=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^a-\left(\frac{n}{n+2}\right)^a\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^a-\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^a\\
&=\left(1+a\left(-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\right)-\left(1+a\left(-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\right)\\
&=a\left(\frac{-1}{(n+2)(n+1)}\right)+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)
\end{align}$

However, now it looks like I need to multiply $n^2$ instead of $n$ to the fraction $\frac{f(n)}{\frac{1}{n^a}}$.
(Of course, this is wrong, since trying out a limit like $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(n)}{\frac{1}{n^{a+2}}}$ on a computer algebra system gives $\infty$.)

Edit: After maxmilgram's comment, my corrected working is as follows:
$\begin{align}\frac{f(n)}{\frac{1}{n^a}}&=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^a-\left(\frac{n}{n+2}\right)^a\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^a-\left(1-\frac{2}{n+2}\right)^a\\
&=\left(1+a\left(-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\right)-\left(1+a\left(-\frac{2}{n+2}\right)+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)\right)\\
&=a\left(\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)}\right)+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)
\end{align}$

which indeed suggests $f(n)\sim kg(n)$ for some constant $k$.

Comment: Hint: apply the mean value theorem to the function $\frac1{x^a}$ on the interval $x\in[n+1,n+2]$.

Comment: There is a small error in the second term. It shoul read $\frac{-2}{n+2}$ instead of $\frac{-1}{n+2}$. This yields an extra $n$.

Comment: Well, after your edit, then you have the solution... $g(n)=1/n^{a+1}$, so if instead of dividing by $1/n^a$ you divide by $g(n)$. you get the extra factor $n$ you need at the end:
$$
\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = a\left (\frac{n^2}{(n+2)(n+1)} \right) + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\right) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} a
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your mistake.** It's minor, but has big implications: you wrote
$$
\left(\frac{n}{n+2}\right)^a = \left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^a
$$
instead of
$$
\left(\frac{n}{n+2}\right)^a = \left(1-\frac{2}{n+2}\right)^a
$$
so a dominating term which shouldn't have cancelled disappeared.

---

**Solution.**
*Using Taylor expansions; we will invoke the fact that, for any fixed $\alpha$,
$$
(1+x)^\alpha = 1+\alpha x + o(x) \tag{1}
$$
as $x\to 0$.*

---

Assume $a\neq 0$. We have, from (1) and the fact that $1/n\to 0$
$$\begin{align}
f(n) 
&= \frac{1}{(n+1)^a} - \frac{1}{(n+2)^a}
= \frac{1}{n^a}\left(\frac{1}{(1+1/n)^a} - \frac{1}{(1+2/n)^a} \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n^a}\left(\frac{1}{1+a/n + o(1/n)} - \frac{1}{1+2a/n + o(1/n)} \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n^a}\left(1- \frac{a}{n} + o\!\left(\frac1n\right) - \left(1- \frac{2a}{n} + o\!\left(\frac1n\right)\right) \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n^a}\left(\frac{a}{n} + o\!\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\\
&= \frac{a}{n^{a+1}}+o\!\left(\frac1n\right)\\
&= a \cdot g(n) + o(g(n))
\end{align}$$
so indeed,
$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = a
$, and thus $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$.

Comment: Thank you. May I know which part of my working is problematic? Thanks maxmilgram for answering!

Comment: @JiaChengSun Good point, I forgot to point out the (minor) mistake you made. I have edited my answer to address this.

Answer (score 2):

For large $n$
$$
\frac1{(n+1)^a}-\frac1{(n+2)^a}= n^{-a}(1+\dfrac1n)^{-a}-n^{-a}(1+\dfrac2n)^{-a}\\\approx n^{-a}(1-\frac an)-n^{-a}(1-\frac{2a}n)=n^{-a}\frac an=\frac a{n^{a+1}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)^a}-\frac{1}{(n+2)^a}= \frac{(n+2)^a-(n+1)^a}{(n^2+3n+2)^a}$$
Using $b^n -a^n=(b-a)(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}a+b^{n-3}a^2+.....+a^{n-1})$
$$=\frac{(n+2-n-1)((n+2)^{a-1}+(n+2)^{a-2}(n+1)+(n+2)^{a-3}(n+1)^{2}+.....+(n+1)^{a-1})}{(n^2+3n+2)^a}$$

$$=\frac{(n+2)^{a-1}+(n+2)^{a-2}(n+1)+(n+2)^{a-3}(n+1)^{2}+.....+(n+1)^{a-1}}{(n^2+3n+2)^a}$$
$$=\frac{(n)^{a-1}((1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-1}+(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-2}(1+\frac{1}{n})+(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-3}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{2}+.....+(1+\frac{1}{n})^{a-1})}{(n^2+3n+2)^a}$$
$$f(n)=\frac{(n)^{a-1}((1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-1}+(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-2}(1+\frac{1}{n})+(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-3}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{2}+.....+(1+\frac{1}{n})^{a-1})}{n^{2a}(1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2})^a}$$

$$g(n)=\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\frac{\frac{(n)^{a-1}((1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-1}+(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-2}(1+\frac{1}{n})+(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-3}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{2}+.....+(1+\frac{1}{n})^{a-1})}{n^{2a}(1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2})^a}}{\frac{1}{n^{a+1}}}$$

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n)^{2a}((1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-1}+(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-2}(1+\frac{1}{n})+(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-3}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{2}+.....+(1+\frac{1}{n})^{a-1})}{n^{2a}(1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2})^a}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-1}+(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-2}(1+\frac{1}{n})+(1+\frac{2}{n})^{a-3}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{2}+.....+(1+\frac{1}{n})^{a-1}}{(1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2})^a}$$
$$=\frac{(1)(a)}{1}=a$$

Answer (score 1):

The binomial series
$$(1+z)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k} z^k$$ with the choice $\alpha = -a$ and $z \in \{1/n, 2/n\}$ yields $$\begin{align}
n^{-a} \left( (1 + 1/n)^{-a} - (1 + 2/n)^{-a} \right) &= n^{-a} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-a}{k} \left( n^{-k} - (n/2)^{-k} \right) \\
&= n^{-a} \left( \frac{a}{n} - \frac{3a(a+1)}{2n^2} + \frac{7a(a+1)(a+2)}{6n^3} - \cdots \right)
\end{align}$$
where the general term in the sum is $$(-1)^{k+1} \binom{a+k-1}{k} (2^k-1) n^{-k}.$$ Thus as $n \to \infty$, the behavior of the given expression is asymptotic to $a n^{-(a+1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
f(n) = a\int_{n + 1}^{n + 2} {g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t} 
$$
and
$$
a \cdot g(n + 2) < a\int_{n + 1}^{n + 2} {g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}  < a \cdot g(n + 1),
$$
due to the monotonicity of $g$. Finally, observe that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{g(n + 2)}}{{g(n)}}=1,\qquad\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{g(n + 1)}}{{g(n)}} = 1.
$$
Thus, by the squeeze theorem,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(n)}}{{g(n)}} = a.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general and looking for an approximation of
$$z=\frac{1}{(n+p)^a}-\frac{1}{(n+q)^a}\qquad \text{for} \quad a>0$$

$$y=\frac{1}{(n+r)^a}\implies \log(y)=-a\log(n+r)=-a\log(n)-a\log \left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right) $$

So, by Taylor expansion for large values of $n$
$$\log(y)=-a \log(n)-a\left(\frac{r}{n}-\frac{r^2}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$
$$y=n^{-a}\left(1-\frac{a r}{n}+\frac{a(a+1)  r^2}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$ Applied twice
$$z \sim n^{-a}\left(\frac{a (q-p)}{n}+\frac{(a-1) a (p-q) (p+q)}{2
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$
$$z \sim a  (q-p)n^{-(a+1)}\left(1-\frac{(a+1) (p+q)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$
Limited to the first order
$$z \sim a(q-p)\,n^{-(a+1)}$$